# How to hook into OpenSSL shared library?

Tags: function-hooking

To preface, I am not a well-versed developer in the whole business of reverse engineering or even most basic programming. This is a project I made with the goal of attempting to replicate an existing connection.

Essentially, there is an application that will send server requests that I wish to snoop on and replicate. However, I've tried using Fiddler, Wireshark and a number of other network sniffing applications to try to intercept these packets, but nothing shows up. I was tipped off that it may be useful to try to "hook" into the SSL_read and SSL_write functions as the application makes use of the OpenSSL library. However, I have no idea how to do that.

The dll in question is libssl-1_1.dll. When I attempted to look up how to hook into it, I found a bunch of results where the user could compile a C file to hook into it. I found another developer had used EasyHook to do so, but I have no idea how to generate the files to do so. I would appreciate any assistance in this matter, especially if it's something I can easily follow.

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2252/what-is-dll-injection-and-how-is-it-used-for-reversing/2255#2255